# how do I put a gradient on a x3dom shape?

Tags: x3dom

This is a simple question. How do I put a gradient on a x3dom shape? I have this:

```
<shape>
    <appearance>
        <material diffuseColor='green'></material>
    </appearance>
    <box height="1" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately its not possible on most primitive shapes
i found this thread on x3d list
http://www.web3d.org/x3d/publiclists/x3dpublic_list_archives/0504/msg00104.html

here is how you can do it on a cylinder notice the pixel texture, thats the meat and potatoes:

```
<X3D>
<Scene>
<NavigationInfo headlight='FALSE' type='"EXAMINE" "ANY"' />
<DirectionalLight ambientIntensity='0.5' direction='1 -0.5 -1' />
<Viewpoint DEF='VP1' position='0 0 10' orientation='0 1 0 0' fieldOfView='0.785398'      description = "Front" />
 <Transform translation='0 0 0'> 
  <Shape>
    <Appearance>
      <Material/>
      <PixelTexture image='1 2 3 0xFF0000 0x0000FF' repeatS='FALSE' repeatT='FALSE' />
    </Appearance>
    <Cylinder height='4' />
  </Shape>
</Transform>
</Scene>
</X3D>
```